# Calculate payment for retirement in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Georgia McBeal is trying to save for her retirement. She believes she can earn 10% on
average each year on her retirement fund. Assume that at the beginning of each of the
next 40 years, Georgia will allocate x pounds to her retirement fund. If at the beginning of
a year Georgia has y pounds in her fund, by the end of year, it will grow to 1.1y pounds.

How much should Georgia allocate to her retirement fund each year to ensure that she
will have £1 million at the end of 40 years?

Comment: I have tried using Goal Seek but no luck.

Comment: Is PPMT(rate, per, nper, pv, [fv], [type]) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **PMT function** will help you with this question:

- Rate: Yield, in this case 10% annually
- Nper: Amount of periods, since Georgia is only contributing annually, it will be 40 periods
- PV: Present Value is 0, as Georgia has currently nothing saved up
- FV: Future Value is the amount she is trying to save up, in this case £1MM
- Type: 1, which indicates that the amount is contributed at the beginning of the year

> =PMT(10%;40;0;1000000;1)

Georgia will have to save £2,054.01 per year in order to reach her savings goal.

Answer (score 0):

Think about this year on year (assuming she allocates the same amount each year):

In year 1, Georgia allocates x pounds.

In year 2, Georgia allocates x pounds etc.

So at the end of year 1, Georgia has:

```
x pounds.
```

At the end of year 2, Georgia has:

```
x pounds + x*1.1.
```

At the end of year 3, Georgia has:

```
x + 1.1x + (1.1^2)*x...
```

...so at the end of year forty, Georgia has:

```
`f(40) = x + 1.1x + ... + (1.1^39)*x`.
```

Now solve for

```
`f(40) >= 1,000,000`...
```